# Adding an Export Format for files in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

Helloo,

I have added the `ImportExportActionModelAdmin` function in my Admin for Project, but I can not find the option to choose the format of the file to download and option to export orders.

I have followed the following documnetation about Import and Export but still the action function didn't appear

https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#exporting-via-admin-action

How do I add that option to export for different formate when I select orders? This is the print for how I want it to be I got it from tutorial following the same steps in the documentation

[image]

Here is the admin.py

```
def order_pdf(obj):
    return mark_safe('<a href="{}">PDF</a>'.format(reverse('core:admin_order_pdf', args=[obj.id])))


order_pdf.short_description = 'Order PDF'

class OrderAdmin(ImportExportActionModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', ....., order_pdf]
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to be clearer about the problem?  Your screenshot shows both the Action and the Format appearing on screen.  Also, you could load the example app and use that as a basis for what you want to do.

Comment: This is the print for how I want it to be, I got it from tutorial following the same steps in the documentation for me it is not showing this option while following the same steps

Answer (score -1):

these are Actions and i recommend to read [all the docs about it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/actions/) do the best practice